# Can a dictionary value be assigned as the key?

Tags: python

I have this dictionary:

```
{'key': [1, 2130, 0, 279, 90, 92, 193, 1]}
```

And i want the key to always be the 3rd column according to the specific line that is read at the time.

I read  a csv text file and build it into a dictionary per line. So for every line read, a dictionary is generated with the 'key' and all of the values from the CSV in the specific line.

So for an example:

```
{'key': [1, 2130, 0, 279, 90, 92, 193, 1]}
{'key': [2, 2214, 0, 382, 71, 77, 211, 1]}
{'key': [3, 169, 172, 691, 302, 15, 22, 1]}
{'key': [4, 215, 363, 514, 41, 35, 172, 1]}
```

The key in the first line should be 0, then 0, then 172 and then 363.

Comment: But dictionary keys have to be unique, right? Your first two keys would both be 0.

Comment: @MaxPower could you please make your explanation clearer?

Comment: So you have a list of dicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> D = {'key': [1, 2130, 0, 279, 90, 92, 193, 1]}
>>> D[D.pop('key')[2]] = D['key']
>>> D
{0: [1, 2130, 0, 279, 90, 92, 193, 1]}
```

Comment: This is exactly what  i needed... Thank you sir. I would have never thought of that alone. I cannot vote up since i just lost my 15 reputation. Damn you cruel people! I'm still a noob... :(

Answer (score 1):

> And I want the key to always be the 3rd column according to the
>   specific line that is read at the time.
>
> I read a csv text file and build it into a dictionary per line.

Are you sure you aren't looking for [`DictReader`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)?:

```
import csv

with open('somefile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    lines = list(reader)
```

If `somefile.csv` has the following content:

```
Name, Age
John, 14
Mary, 15
Adam Smith, 40
```

`lines` will be:

```
[{'Name': 'John', ' Age': ' 14'}, {'Name': 'Mary', ' Age': ' 15'}, {'Name': 'Adam Smith', ' Age': ' 40'}]
```